# Weird UIPickerView bug

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

[UIPickerView Glitch http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/6858/upshotv42weqbe.png](http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/6858/upshotv42weqbe.png)

Here is a picture of the main view for an app I'm making, the thing at the bottom is supposed to be a UIPickerView. I have the UIPickerView view controller in its own `.h` and `.m` files, separate from the main view controller's. could this be the problem?

here is the code that (should, I pretty much copied it from a tutorial) populate the UIPickerview with the contents of an array:  `[super viewDidLoad];`

```
arrayCrops = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[arrayCrops addObject:@"Corn"];
[arrayCrops addObject:@"Soybeans"];
[arrayCrops addObject:@"Soft Red Winter Wheat"];
[arrayCrops addObject:@"Hard Red Winter Wheat"];
[arrayCrops addObject:@"Cotton"];
[arrayCrops addObject:@"Barley"];
[arrayCrops addObject:@"Oats"];
[arrayCrops addObject:@"Milo"];
[arrayCrops addObject:@"Alfalfa"];
[arrayCrops addObject:@"Grass"];
[arrayCrops addObject:@"Sorghum"];
```

and the arrayCrops is an ivar so thats why its not a new instance here.

Comment: So the problem is that the picker view is all black?  What methods of UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate have been implemented?  At least show the titleForRow method.

Comment: Have you scaled or otherwise altered the geometry of the UIPickerView?

Comment: ok, i've kind of fixed the problem, I had the data source and delegate connections hooked up to the main view controller and the picker view controller, but now the app wont let me do anything, not even press the buttons.

Comment: ok, ive fixed the last problem, but now when I press the picker view it gives me a SIGABRT.